# Nonexact duplication, sum rows in pivot table

Tags: sum

I have a spreadsheet for payroll that is populated from a seperate spreadsheet. Occasionally,one of our workers will get a promotion. That promotion shows on the timesheets: ex. Smith, Adam Position becomes Smith, Adam Promotion.
This data is then populated into a pivot table where Smith, Adam Position and Smith, Adam Promotion show in separate cells. Currently, we are manually adding the two data sets so that payroll gets a single number instead of multiple. I would like to simplify this tasks. I am using excel 2003, so some more advanced functions don't work.
Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use a different field (a unique identifier) to identify Smith, Adam (e.g., an employee ID number), but if that's not available, then you could take the following approach:

(Suppose that "Smith, Adam Position" is in A1.)

You could add an additional column that extracts the last name, the comma, and then whatever the next word is. For example, from

Smith, Adam Analyst

you would get Smith, Adam. Unfortunately, this means that If you have something like

Jones, Mary Ellen Consultant

you would end up with Jones, Mary. If you think you can live with that, this solution could work. The way you would extract that would be with the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",",",1),FIND(" ",A1)-1),",",", ",1)
```

And then build your pivot table on that field.